# To append numbers in the specified elements of a list

Tags: python, string, list

Here is my list and I need to append number where the alphabet is there in this list:

```
list1=list(some_list)
```

Here is the example of the list1:

```
list1=[ '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'G', 'S', 'H', 'S', 'M', 'R', 'Y', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'S', 'V', 'S', 'R', 'P', 'G']
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'G', 'S', 'H', 'S', 'M', 'R', 'Y', '-', '-', '-']
```

Desired Output should be:

```
list1=[ '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '1G', '2S', '3H', '4S', '5M', '6R', '7Y', '8F', '9F', '10T', '11S', '12V', '13S', '14R', '15P', '16G']
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '1G', '2S', '3H', '4S', '5M', '6R', '7Y', '-', '-', '-']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
l1 = [ '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'G', 'S', 'H', 'S', 'M', 'R', 'Y', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'S', 'V', 'S', 'R', 'P', 'G']
c = 1
for i, v in enumerate(l1):
    if v.isalpha():
        l1[i] = str(c)+v
        c+=1
print(l1)
```

**Output:**

```
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '1G', '2S', '3H', '4S', '5M', '6R', '7Y', '8F', '9F', '10T', '11S', '12V', '13S', '14R', '15P', '16G']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension with `str.isalpha`, `itertools.count` and f-strings. Formatted string literals are supported in Python 3.6+.

```
from itertools import count

c = count(1)
res = [i if not i.isalpha() else f'{next(c)}{i}' for i in list1]
```

Result:

```
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '1G', '2S', '3H', '4S', '5M', '6R',
'7Y', '8F', '9F', '10T', '11S', '12V', '13S', '14R', '15P', '16G']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer